# Show div after submit click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

How can I show a div content after a form is submitted, and make form to hide, I know is jquery but I dont know how to do it here is my form

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>

    <!-- Add this line in your form -->
    <div class="QapTcha"></div> <br><br>

    <input style="margin-left:20px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and here is my div

```
<div class="follow">database line 1</div>
<div class="follow">database line 2</div>
```

can you help me?

Comment: Could you post the full code for what you're trying to do here or on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: i will make a jsfiddle

Comment: I can't make a jsfiddle becouse i also use php how to give you the code?     here is website were i test it http://websiteres.hol.es/captcha/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP on the backend the when you do all the backend tast and you redirect the user where your page is then simply append `?formsub=1` in the URL, and check it's presence via JS

```
// Function to fetch param from URL

 function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    if(getParameterByName("formsub") == "1")
    {
    $("form").fadeOut();
    $(".follow").fadeIn();
    }
```

Comment: This only half works - the page will refresh when you submit the form so although the solution is correct and the javascript will hide the form and show the divs, the page will refresh and the form will show again. You will need to submit the form with AJAX and use similar code to that provided by void to hide it and show the divs on receipt of a successful call back from your AJAX function.

Comment: I thought that he must be submitting the form via AJAX.

Comment: I am asking you to that so that i can test the form by just pressing the submit button instead of moving that slider again and again. Just comment the line `$('.QapTcha').QapTcha({disabledSubmit:true,autoRevert:true,autoSubmit:true});` temporarily.

Comment: Bro, I guess you also need to comment those .js and the .css, Because their is no form in your site. Dont worry we will get it back. Thats how we debug

Comment: done now? here is what i want to implement http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/qaptcha/

Comment: Why did you commented jquery.js? Uncomment it.

Comment: Or upload this code on dropbox and give me its link

Comment: Now just access the link http://websiteres.hol.es/captcha/. Click on submit and you can see the form disappearing after submission.

Comment: is back done after submit form hides but div is always there

Comment: Just add css `.follow{display:none}`

Comment: here is the code http://www.fileshare.ro/e31329707

Comment: Whats the need of sharing the file now. I guess it is working. Just add the CSS and uncomment what you commented. It will work.

Comment: is working but if i refresh it updates how can i make it turn back to captcha if users tryes to refresh? or insert direct url?

Comment: Just kidding, for that you might need to use cookies. Or if your server handles PHP then you can use session variables. :)

Comment: download the file and take a look if you can please :D